# How to add an image to a table when the direction is in a variable (in SQL)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to add an image to a table where the datatype is a varbinary(MAX) and which is received when calling a procedure, the problem is that usually, I add the image to the table by using the following code:

```
insert into Image select * from openrowset (bulk  N'D:\Computer Programing\z Programas\SQL Practicas\images\ cell shoes.png', single_blob) as image
```

(the table has only 1 non-key parameter that is why I don't specify the parameter I'm adding), but now that I am trying to add the image by using a variable it doesn't work (I am assuming is because the structure of the code, which I don't really understand (I just stole it :D)). Anyway, the problematic code is the one that follows:

```
create procedure CrearProducto (@nombre nvarchar(50), @precio money, @descripcion varchar(200), @image varbinary(MAX), @username varchar(20))
as
    --"Producto" is just another table
    insert into Producto values (@nombre, @precio, @descripcion, NULL, NULL, NULL, 00)

    --Here is where I have the problem with the variable @image
    insert into Image select * from openrowset (bulk  @image, single_blob) as image

    --Again I am having the same problem, this time I'm trying to put the result in a variable to make a comparation at the end
    declare @image2 varbinary(MAX) = (select * from openrowset (bulk  @image, single_blob) as image)
    update Producto set id_Image = (select id_Image from Image where image = @image2)
go
```

If you know any other way to add an image to a table it would also be helpfull.
Thanks for the help, I hope is not anything too complicated and that I am not making too mistakes hahaha, good day.

Comment: Gee, its kinda hard to solve your problem without you sharing the specific text of the problem.  We cannot guess what problem(s) you are seeing for each of the attempts.

Answer (score 0):

In your original, working code:

```
insert into Image select * from openrowset (bulk  N'D:\Computer Programing\z Programas\SQL Practicas\images\ cell shoes.png', single_blob) as image
```

...you pass the image file path in to the `OPENROWSET` parameter. It appears in the stored procedure that you are using to replace it you are passing the `@image` parameter in place of the file path. However, `@image` is now the byte array of the image file itself, not the path to the file (based on its type of varbinary(max) rather than varchar(n)). You should be just setting the value of the varbinary(max) image column in the database to the value of the `@image` variable. i.e. (and here I'm having to guess the schema):

```
create procedure CrearProducto (@nombre nvarchar(50), @precio money, @descripcion varchar(200), @image varbinary(MAX), @username varchar(20))
as
    --"Producto" is just another table
    insert into Producto values (@nombre, @precio, @descripcion, NULL, NULL, NULL, 00)

    insert into Image
    values (@image)

    update Producto 
    set id_Image = image
    -- You appear to be missing a WHERE clause here. This will set all Producto rows
go
```